# get Maximum COntent Offset in UItextVew iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

On Click of a button the data in my TextView is appended. I want that when content reaches the end of the textView it should scroll automatically.

The data is appended by "\n"'s so what I need is to set the rectTovisile to he maximum Content Offset , but I dont know how to get the maximum content offset.

If you have any oher method doProvide.

codeBehind:

```
- (IBAction) onLap
{   
    NSString *lapCatch = ......;

    myUITextView.text = [myUITextView.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"myData: %@ \n",lapCatch];
}
```

Comment: if you want the textview should scroll, when we content reaches at the end of textview height, then it will be better to read UIScrollView documentation else ACB answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
if (myUITextView.text.length > 0) {
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(myUITextView.text.length - 1, 1);
  [myUITextView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
}
```

Comment: In my case myUITextView.text.length - 2, 1 worked but thats cool too